# How can I remove regular months' obervations in an unstructured series in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = dput(sent_results_mp)
structure(list(Date = structure(c(11690, 11725, 11753, 11781, 
11809, 11844, 11872, 11942, 11970, 11998, 12026, 12061, 12089, 
12117, 12145, 12180, 12208, 12243, 12299, 12327, 12362, 12390, 
12425, 12453, 12481, 12509, 12544, 12572, 12600, 12663, 12698, 
12726, 12754, 12796, 12817, 12845, 12880, 12907, 12936, 12971, 
13027, 13062, 13090, 13118, 13160, 13181, 13209, 13244, 13272, 
13307, 13335, 13363, 13391, 13426, 13454, 13489, 13524, 13552, 
13580, 13615, 13643, 13670, 13699, 13762, 13790, 13825, 13853, 
13888, 13916, 13944, 13979, 14007, 14035, 14063, 14098, 14126, 
14154, 14189, 14217, 14259, 14280, 14308, 14336, 14371, 14399, 
14427, 14462, 14490, 14525, 14553, 14581, 14623, 14644, 14672, 
14707, 14735, 14770, 14798, 14826, 14854, 14889, 14917, 14945, 
14987, 15008, 15036, 15071, 15099, 15134, 15162, 15190, 15225, 
15253, 15281, 15316, 15351, 15379, 15407, 15434, 15463, 15497, 
15526, 15554, 15589, 15617, 15652, 15680, 15715, 15743, 15771, 
15799, 15827, 15862, 15890, 15918, 15953, 15980, 16016, 16044, 
16079, 16107, 16135, 16163, 16198, 16226, 16254, 16289, 16317, 
16345, 16380, 16408, 16457, 16499, 16540, 16589, 16632, 16681, 
16730, 16772, 16821, 16870, 16912, 16954, 17003, 17052, 17094, 
17143, 17185, 17234, 17283, 17325, 17367, 17416, 17465, 17514, 
17556, 17598, 17647, 17696, 17738, 17787, 17829, 17878, 17920, 
17962, 17996, 18053, 18102, 18151, 18193, 18242, 18284, 18333, 
18382, 18417, 18459, 18515, 18564, 18606), class = "Date"), Sentiment = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, -0.0957529552593197, -0.239862173958995, 0, 0, 0, -0.188924269202003, 
-0.091167278669553, 0, -0.135208666258976, -0.234113624774356, 
-0.212585339838951, -0.105651305696646, -0.222774417797656, -0.159894235955241, 
-0.138472470255942, -0.0585150174036769, 0.103711250566817, 0.22031952297964, 
0.145250201234944, -0.0323994910462342, 0.111593250830965, 0.0295247989691986, 
0, 0.212482042926666, 0.158605081733718, 0.191920529302748, 0.173414462996843, 
0.216876858126887, 0.20756261971968, 0.154883876782037, 0.149137898593547, 
0.142165761354657, 0.121643683652311, 0.143972172018566, 0.0657414955655748, 
-0.0324914378153873, 0.22264327839293, 0.185010294208908, 0.200374287833188, 
0.0673440137703783, 0.0929770244712388, 0.113554686221999, 0.182856427591615, 
0.0934514885524806, 0.183617393098071, 0.0937019320979792, 0.159373306262786, 
0.189215896294599, 0.112404940944111, 0.148174048572046, 0.141732287695358, 
0.110064057625983, 0.0551168195596121, 0.123436755747825, 0.133480320068247, 
0.101616646400401, 0.109118646472558, 0.13840615378245, 0.063620964728031, 
-0.0929040604032753, 0.0213563501297979, 0.0477819585658106, 
0.0521622996105026, 0.116380748001251, 0.0145928432680972, 0.130906487222809, 
0.242361449110559, 0.122366901526266, 0.189549946862169, 0.121341708778681, 
0.0275950455528882, 0.115830049217305, -0.00268196934335387, 
-0.268667095406521, -0.270654675922787, -0.345097118931143, -0.201666970593853, 
-0.197870820068962, -0.183318344286775, -0.256780314062594, -0.164952289086926, 
-0.203040493784049, -0.0953052320370853, -0.0564353925542141, 
-0.0595365444481821, -0.0391431509940865, -0.158559094494205, 
-0.103666510741687, -0.0341276356813399, -0.145250783683547, 
-0.0348102368055625, -0.11164828986622, -0.153872166218408, -0.172037964130696, 
-0.143868340198388, -0.253504128423768, -0.161731136069997, -0.0757134096682664, 
-0.24850284019793, -0.0241736860282622, -0.0497985627029049, 
0.0267362983301218, -0.0288807405823324, -0.0216738497959909, 
-0.0547198276698082, -0.0713004669575829, -0.179452611448087, 
-0.0882044859593271, -0.262589845197242, -0.277194378086572, 
-0.264553715711326, -0.259524252590977, -0.196382049608858, -0.0759425223156328, 
-0.0361527200578723, -0.106850259008264, -0.286292773362804, 
-0.25954572063577, -0.28324826826043, -0.290781100752149, -0.221078940043079, 
-0.203717181838236, -0.156778915779193, -0.0518897691822025, 
-0.192229960033653, -0.170680784237861, -0.270654390695637, -0.305547637220867, 
-0.077830807264447, -0.142463997328291, -0.111816767186701, -0.0969791693314262, 
-0.0977361569524874, -0.273767496166023, -0.25730447171265, -0.271029007126539, 
-0.252917481283751, -0.242632588726111, -0.0811418391092237, 
-0.215566014069223, -0.362387647325206, -0.270342963775206, -0.314850509295431, 
-0.337486756477923, -0.285711580880554, -0.340974038135234, -0.331945731128118, 
-0.304930629110979, -0.150278570470029, -0.283028615895731, -0.277429801826168, 
-0.185458849789886, -0.277688809057794, -0.22402331728913, -0.375964402684551, 
-0.255242751090043, -0.344736427759783, -0.309107710644531, -0.293704494677478, 
-0.243479266198671, -0.245051446889861, -0.231687103050292, -0.350613730820339, 
-0.169486098633503, -0.311849636896508, -0.223447284729041, -0.119431392144917, 
-0.275098935303954, -0.22189613629342, -0.299753093156644, -0.213188459452649, 
-0.194131767679836, -0.293604768058008, -0.235407074042252, -0.304132799905395, 
-0.34748336796163, -0.362535972556536, -0.321477097322425, -0.364037876416921, 
-0.313450665525883, -0.294676350612345, -0.254149309015538, -0.232363154687674, 
-0.313000245989788, -0.326964317594564, -0.26214055036952, -0.268116079703687, 
-0.267480139301619, -0.319864093982952, -0.360481609256352, -0.314464988256011, 
-0.298918676729976, -0.278082463263552, -0.270358321007133, -0.328174016516938
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -199L))
```

This dataframe is not regular in its frequency. With the following code, you can see the missing months in the series that would have made it monthly:

```
missingMonths <- lapply(split(df,format(as.Date(df$Date),"%Y")), 
                        function(x) month.name[setdiff(seq(12),as.numeric(format(as.Date(x$Date),"%m")))])

missingMonths

# this is from 2015 to 2020

$`2015`
[1] "February" "May"      "August"   "November"

$`2016`
[1] "February" "May"      "August"   "November"

$`2017`
[1] "February" "May"      "August"   "November"

$`2018`
[1] "February" "May"      "August"   "November"

$`2019`
[1] "February" "May"      "August"   "November"

$`2020`
[1] "February" "May"      "August"   "November"
```

I only printed the missing months from 2015 to 2020 because they show a pattern, i.e. always the same four months come up. What I would like to do is to make the observation missing for the same months in previous years as well. Let me take an example. This is the series in 2014, with no missing months:

```
          Date   Sentiment
140 2014-01-09 -0.27102901
141 2014-02-06 -0.25291748
142 2014-03-06 -0.24263259
143 2014-04-03 -0.08114184
144 2014-05-08 -0.21556601
145 2014-06-05 -0.36238765
146 2014-07-03 -0.27034296
147 2014-08-07 -0.31485051
148 2014-09-04 -0.33748676
149 2014-10-02 -0.28571158
150 2014-11-06 -0.34097404
151 2014-12-04 -0.33194573

# Yet, I want to remove the observations for February, May, August and November by taking the mean with the previous month. I would get:

          Date   Sentiment
140 2014-01-09  # this should be the mean between jan and feb
142 2014-03-06 -0.24263259
143 2014-04-03  # this should be the mean of april and may
145 2014-06-05 -0.36238765
146 2014-07-03  # this should be the mean of july and august
148 2014-09-04 -0.33748676
149 2014-10-02  # this should be the mean of october and november
151 2014-12-04 -0.33194573
```

This should be applied to all the years.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: it's always "February", "May", "August", "November"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the months manually from the complete data you could do :

```
library(dplyr)
missingMonths <- c(2, 5, 8, 11)

df %>%
  group_by(group = cumsum(!as.numeric(format(Date, '%m')) %in% missingMonths)) %>%
  summarise(Date = first(Date), 
            Sentiment = mean(Sentiment)) %>%
  select(-group)

#    Date       Sentiment
#   <date>         <dbl>
# 1 2002-01-03    0     
# 2 2002-03-07    0     
# 3 2002-04-04   -0.0479
# 4 2002-06-06   -0.240 
# 5 2002-07-04    0     
# 6 2002-09-12    0     
# 7 2002-10-10   -0.0945
# 8 2002-12-05   -0.0912
# 9 2003-01-09   -0.0676
#10 2003-03-06   -0.234 
# … with 141 more rows
```

Comment: in this way, however, you are not taking the mean of the observation of the month eliminated and its previous one

Comment: Why, for example in 2002, 2003, etc., February and May are still there? @Ronak Shah

Comment: Ohh..that is because `format` returns character values like '02', '05' which do not match with `missingMonths`. I converted them to numeric and I guess it works now?

Answer (score 1):

You may exploit the `months` function. Analogously, we may use `substr` to get the years. This enables us to use `table` to count zero values `z` which we use for subsetting.

```
z <- rowSums(with(df, table(months(Date), substr(Date, 1, 4))) == 0)
res <- df[months(df$Date) %in% names(z[z == 0]), ]
head(res)
#         Date  Sentiment
# 1 2002-01-03  0.0000000
# 3 2002-03-07  0.0000000
# 4 2002-04-04  0.0000000
# 6 2002-06-06 -0.2398622
# 7 2002-07-04  0.0000000
# 9 2002-10-10  0.0000000
```

*Check:*

```
with(res, table(months(res$Date), substr(res$Date, 1, 4)))
#          2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2020
# April       1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
# December    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
# January     1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
# July        1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
# June        1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
# March       1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
# October     1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
```

#### Edit

To impute as described in comment below you could use a `"flag"` to calculate the mean, then delete flagged rows afterwards.

```
res2 <- within(df, {
  flag <- ifelse(months(Date) %in% names(z[z == 0]), 0, 1)
  Sentiment <- ave(Sentiment, cumsum(flag == 0), FUN=mean)
})

res2 <- res2[res2$flag == 0, 1:2]
head(res2)
#         Date   Sentiment
# 1 2002-01-03  0.00000000
# 3 2002-03-07  0.00000000
# 4 2002-04-04 -0.04787648
# 6 2002-06-06 -0.23986217
# 7 2002-07-04  0.00000000
# 9 2002-10-10 -0.09446213
```

Comment: Almost there! Do you manage to add the mean between the observation you delete and its previous observation? If "February" observation goes away, "January" value must be the mean of "January" and "February" and so on

Comment: @Rollo99 Check the updated answer to see if it works.

Comment: It does! Great solution as well! Thanks so much